# Wordpress wp_insert_post is creating new Taxonomy term when creating new custom post

Tags: php, wordpress

In my WordPress v5.5.1, I am using public front-end form to create custom post type. I am saving the form data as custom post with below code:

```
function save_function() {
   // MESSAGE FIELDS
    $public_post = array(
        'post_title' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'title'),
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_type' => 'message',
        'post_status' => 'pending',
        'tax_input' => array(
            'my_custom_taxonomy' => array(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'subject')) // subject is a HTML select which captures option value contains term_id which is generated using get_terms.
        )
    );

    wp_insert_post($public_post);
}
```

Instead of `'tax_input'` tag this post to the existing custom_taxonomy term, it is creating a duplicate term with `term_id` as term name.

Comment: Check if the tax term already exists, and if it doesn't, then create it before insertion - then you can get your newly created term_taxonomy_id, and use that in the insertion. - if it already does exist, then get the term_taxonomy_id of it, and use that for insertion.

Comment: like this : https://refactored.co/blog/how-to-use-wp_insert_post-tax_input

Comment: Before posting here at SE I have tried it, issue I had with that code is neither it is creating duplicate term nor it is assigning the custom_post to the term. I have tested using both `term_id` and `term_taxonomy_id`.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Plese Try This Func**

```
   function save_function()
{

    $subject_term = 'subject';
    $my_subject_term = term_exists($subject_term, 'my_custom_taxonomy');   // check if term in website or no
    // Create Term if it doesn't exist
    if (!$my_subject_term) {
        $my_subject_term = wp_insert_term($subject_term, 'my_custom_taxonomy');
    }
    $custom_tax = array(
        'my_custom_taxonomy' => array(
            $my_subject_term['term_taxonomy_id'],
        )
    );

    // MESSAGE FIELDS
    $public_post = array(
        'post_title' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'title'),
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_type' => 'message',
        'post_status' => 'pending',
        'tax_input' => $custom_tax
    );

    $post_id = wp_insert_post($public_post);

    
}
```